# Laravel Pass Comments with Posts

Tags: php, html, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a One to Many relationship set up for my "announcements" having many "comments".

Currently, when my user loads up the app page, I have it send the 30 most recent announcements like such:

```
Route::get('/app', function () {
    $posts =      Announcement::take(30)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return View::make('app')->with([
        //posts
        'posts'       => $posts,
        //orders
        'orders'      => $orders
    ]);
}
```

When I echo out the announcements in blade using a foreach loop through the $posts object, I want to also echo out the comments for each post under the respective post.

Is it possible to pass the comments for a post as part of the actual post object? For example, it would be nice if I could do this:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    //echo out the post
    {{$post->content}}
    //echo out the comments relating to this post
    {{$post->comments}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amr Aly gave you the right answer, and I would like to add on top of it.

When you loop through your comments as he showed you (and you should), it will make a different query for each comment. SO if you have 50 comments, that's 50 more queries.

You can mitigate that by using eager loading

```
 $posts = Announcement::with('comments')
 ->take(30)->orderBy('id', 'desc')
 ->get();
```

Then just loop the way he showed you. THis will limit the queries to 2 only. You can read more from the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

You can add another `foreach` for your comment like this:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
      //echo out the post

       @if($post->comments->count())
          @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
            // {{ $comment }}
          @endforeach
       @endif

@endforeach
```